# how to specify timestamp format for "git-annotating" file

Tags: intellij-idea

In intellij IDEA, when you have GIT VCS, you can do:  -> Git -> Annotate, which yields in-gui variant of `git blame`.

But for some reason the produced timestamps does not respect git settings for some reason (well at least what `git blame` produces is different), "right-clicking annotation, ->options-> show commit timestamp" does nothing, and I did not find possibility to specify format of this.

Motivation: The default format misses time, and uses US date formatting, which is "for its stupid famous order", sorry, I meant famous for its stupid order, and it always takes me 10x the time to figure out, what date is it.

Is there possibility to have there iso timestamp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Go to `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Date Formats`
- enable the *Override system date and time format* checkbox.
- Enter something like `yyyy MM dd kk:mm` in the *Date Format* text field.

This will show your preferred time format (including time stamp if you want) in the Git Blame Annotations.